# How can i trigger an event inside an ajax (success) during multiple verification form to direct to the next page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have multiple verification forms all in one page separated by a sections. so when i click step one's continue button ( submit ) it should insert data and take me to the next page.

My form button

```
<button id="bStep1" type="submit" form="profileForm1" class="next action-button">Continue</button>
```

so when i click this button it should insert data as well as take me to the next page.
below you can see what i use to get data from the form.

```
<script>
$("input").prop('required', true);

$("#bStep1").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formdataStp1 = new FormData(this.form)

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('
        user.profiles.store ')}}',
        data: formdataStp1,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('form was submitted');

        }
    });
});
```

i thought of a solution to trigger an event inside a ajax success didn't quite work as i planned.

below is the function i use to go to the next page

```
(function($) {
    //* Form js
    function verificationForm() {
        //jQuery time
        var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
        var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
        var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

        $(".next").click(function(e) {

            if (animating) return false;
            animating = true;

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

            //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();
            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                step: function(now, mx) {
                    //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                    //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                    scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                    //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                    left = (now * 50) + "%";
                    //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                    opacity = 1 - now;
                    current_fs.css({
                        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                        'position': 'absolute'
                    });
                    next_fs.css({
                        'left': left,
                        'opacity': opacity
                    });
                },
                duration: 800,
                complete: function() {
                    current_fs.hide();
                    animating = false;
                },
                //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                easing: 'easeInOutBack'
            });
        });

        $(".previous").click(function() {
            if (animating) return false;
            animating = true;

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

            //de-activate current step on progressbar
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

            //show the previous fieldset
            previous_fs.show();
            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({
                opacity: 0,
            }, {
                step: function(now, mx) {
                    //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                    //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                    scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                    //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                    left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
                    //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                    opacity = 1 - now;
                    current_fs.css({
                        'left': left,

                    });
                    previous_fs.css({
                        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                        'opacity': opacity
                    });
                },
                duration: 800,
                complete: function() {
                    current_fs.hide();
                    animating = false;
                },
                //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                easing: 'easeInOutBack'
            });
        });

        $(".submit").click(function() {
            return false;
        })
    };
    /*Function Calls*/
    verificationForm();
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the deferreds to run additional functionality after a promise is resolved/successful.

Have you tried adding the .then() method to your ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{route('
        user.profiles.store ')}}',
        data: formdataStp1,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('form was submitted');

        }
}).then( (x) => {
        //run additional functionality after the promise is resolved
        //you can add a parameter (where x is above) if you want to pass
        //something from the response in, default will be the response
        //i would leave it without parameter, and run your code to move to the
        //next page here
});
```

Comment: It worked! but instead of calling the function i directly wrote what needed to be done.

Comment: sweet! congrats. there are also other deferred methods you can call for different reasons, check out the MDN for more info. have fun!